# rtod() not working as expected. Possible misuse?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I am using DDMathParser in my application but I do not understand how to use the function rtod(). I have tried multiple equations but it does not seem to be working.

Some equations do work ex. rtod(acos(0)). But others are not rtod(sin(50)).

Here is an example of the test I did:

```
    > rtod(acos(0))
   rtod(acos(0)) = 90
    > rtod(sin(50))
   rtod(sin(50)) = -15.03297176759753
    >
```

Is it the fact that I am misusing it? I'm not quite sure. But i'm pretty sure that it works someway, for I downloaded an application with DDMathParser built in and there's works just fine.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sin(50)` is not the same as `sin(50 degrees)` because it's decimal (values go up to tenths).
You're feeding in decimals which the trigonometric functions see as radians.

```
   sin(rtod(50))
```

Try it like that.

```
       rtod(50) = 0.872664626 radians
       sin(0.872664626) = 0.766044443
```

Comment: Oh wow you learn something new everyday! To which functions does this apply?

Comment: It should be limited to trigonometrical. Time functions can usually convert things like 31st of February or 12:64 PM

Comment: +1 you'd want `sin(dtor(50))`.  DDMathParser is also clever and lets you use the degree sign to accomplish the same thing:  `sin(50°)`